# PHP String Compare

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to update the price of my product based on ID. ID and price both are string.My code is

```
for($i=1;$i<=$rows;$i++)
{
    $flag=0;
   $result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT id FROM `TABLE 1` ");
   while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
   {     
     $v=strval($cols[$i][0]);
     if(strcmp($row['id'],$v)==0)//id exists in database=> update
     {
        mysqli_query($con,"UPDATE `TABLE 1` SET `price`=".$cols[$i][4]."  WHERE `id`=$v");
        //echo $cols[$i][0];
        $flag=1;
     }
    }
```

Where cols[][] is my multidimensional array. It update the record correctly whose type is integer but not those are String.But product with id 101-1 not updated correctly.Where I am missing?

Comment: What is $cols value ? can you please post your code or can you explain more about.

Comment: $cols stores the values from tab separated file.$cols[$i][0] is column for Id and $cols[$i][4] is price from file respectively.i already echo the result it gives correct value from file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $v or $cols[$i][4] is the String that is not updating correctly,

```
WHERE `id`='$v'

`price`='".$cols[$i][4]."'
```

You need to use ' ' around a string in the query.

Comment: It works one more doubt is I am executing query $result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT id FROM `TABLE 1` "); repeatedly in for loop. Can I used it once and reset Result set. i tried it using mysql_seek_data($result,0) But does not work?

Answer (score 0):

Product id is a primary key and integer and it doesn't support the `101-1` value, from 101-1 which one is id related I mean 101 0r 1, in that use use split  with `-` and use that.

Can you replace this from existing code,

```
 $price = trim($cols[$i][4]);
 mysqli_query($con,"UPDATE `TABLE 1` SET `price`='".$price."'  WHERE `id`='".$v."' ");
```